# How to pass the paramter values to another controller's action in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

Hello friends I am new in zf2. I am creating an action in controller, all things are working correctly. When the form is valid, i would like to pass some of the values to redirect page. how can i do this? Please help me out.

My controller action is

```
public function studenteditAction(){

      $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

     if (!$id) {
         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('manager', array(
             'action' => 'students'
         ));
     }
     $form  = new StudentsForm();

     $request = $this->getRequest();
     if ($request->isPost()) {

         $students = new Students();

         $form->setData($request->getPost());

         if ($form->isValid()) {


            $students->exchangeArray($form->getData());

              $table = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Students\Model\StudentsTable');

              $table->profileStudents($students);

             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('manager',array('controller'=>'manager','action'=>'student-view','id'=>$id,'status' => 'profile-ready'));


         }
     }

     return array(
         'id' => $id,
         'form' => $form,
     );
 }
```

I am unable to get the passed status value on controller's view.
   `'status' => 'profile-ready'`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your routing configuration to accept both 'id' and 'status' values.

```
       'manager' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/manager[/:id][/:status]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Manager',
                    'action'     => 'studentView',
                ),
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id' => '[0-9]*',
                    'status' => '[a-z-]*'
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

**Controller:**

```
public function studentViewAction()
{
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    $status = $this->params()->fromRoute('status');
    return new ViewModel(array('id' => $id, 'status' => $status));
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 
echo $this->id;
echo $this->status;
?>
```

This is how i pass the required values to another controller's action

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this addition of status add status to url like (http://localhost:8084/manager/student-view/1/profile-ready). I just want this status in view not by url, like "echo $this->status"

Comment: The redirect method internally build the URL base on your input parameters. So, you cant do HTTP post operation with redirect() method.